# Pumping fluid out of a tank: how does intake location affect work?

Tags: work

I was working a calculus II problem on the board, teaching how to solve the fluid pumping problems. I drew a tube from the top of the container to the bottom, and a student asked about how that changes the work (as opposed to having a floating intake that lowers with the fluid level).

I reasoned, that gravity would do the work of lowering the fluid down to the intake and so would negate the extra work required to pump it out now from a lower level.

Is that correct?

The total work done by the system doesn't depend on the location of the intake, but the actual work done by the pump will depend on the location of the intake. Correct?

So how would we solve a problem such as: 
Two boxes of $l\times w \times h$ ($h$ is vertical height) are filled with a fluid (of density $\rho$) are connected at the bottom by a thin pipe. The fluid is pumped out through the top of one box, thus the fluid from the second box flows through the pipe at the bottom to the other box to get pumped out. Assume no friction, and that the pump doesn't work extra hard to pull the fluid through the pipe, etc.

[image: fluid pumped from one to another container]

Here's my try:
Work done to empty first container on the right that has the pump: $W_0=\int_0^h \rho g (h-y) A(y) dy=\frac12\rho g l w h^2$ where $A(y)=lw$ is the cross sectional area. Gravity has to do this amount of work bringing the fluid from the second container down to the pipe, but this water just goes into the first container to come to equilibrium level. The pump then does half this same amount of work getting the second container of fluid out from the pipe up (since gravity pushed it up some to get to equilibrium level).

1) Pump works to get 1st container empty: $W_0$.
2) Gravity works to get 2nd container fluid down to pipe and into first container: $-W_0$
3) Pump pulls all fluid from second container out from bottom of 1st container: $W_0/2$ since gravity lifts it halfway due to bringing the two containers to equilibrium level

So the total work done by the pump is $\frac32 W_0$.

Is this anywhere near correct? Is there a better way to conceptualize the problem and set it up?

Comment: u have to specify the height of the pump output

Answer (score 1):

The total work done by a pump may depend on the location of the intake.  For your statement "I drew a tube from the top of the container to the bottom, and a student asked about how that changes the work (as opposed to having a floating intake that lowers with the fluid level)", as long as a pump must get fluid over the top of the tank before sending that fluid to its destination, there is no difference between your piping description and the student's "floating" suction piping. If, on the other hand, you locate the pump suction at the bottom of the tank, there will be a difference because the fluid pressure above the pump suction will help in getting liquid to its destination.

Additionally, for your drawing, if both tanks are open to the atmosphere, the pump will not have to do any work to get liquid from tank 1 to tank 2 ... the liquid will naturally "gravitate" from one tank to the other such that the liquid levels in both tanks remain equal while the pump is emptying the tanks.  On the other hand, if tank 2 is "sealed up" such that the pressure on top of the liquid in that tank is different than atmospheric pressure, you will need to provide somewhat more detail and data before a valid answer can be given.

Comment: David, not sure I agree with your last statement about an opening in the bottom, thinking about siphoning action I believe all 3 situations involve the same amount of work. Also let's suppose jdods was pumping to an uphill reservoir ... that also would be the same work for the 3 situations. ?

Comment: @PhysicsDave, it's going to take more work to get the liquid from the tank to the pump suction if the pump has to "suck" the liquid out of the tank, versus taking the liquid from the bottom of the tank, where the liquid head will automatically gravitate liquid into the pump suction, if the destination tank is at the same level as the source tank.  However, you do make a good point ... if the destination tank is at a higher elevation than the source tank, there should be no difference.  More details from the OP would be welcomed.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. I did mean for the left tank to be open to the air and the pumping work to stop at the top of the right tank so that gravity takes over from there. So the pump actually does less work in this situation than if the two tanks were combined (e.g. right next to each other with the connected wall removed)? If there is more information I need to supply, please let me know somewhat specifically as I'm not a physicist and may be misunderstanding much.

Comment: @jdods, the answer may vary, depending on the exact process that you have in mind.  A more specific picture would be helpful.